# Quartz Job not firing as expected

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

I have following **cronTrigger** Expression in my .NET Application to fire this job every 45 minutes...

```
0 0/45 * * * ?
```

However its firing every 15 and then 45 minutes...for example it fires as below

> 2:15 pm 3:00 pm 3:15 pm 4:00 pm 4:15 pm 5:00 pm

I only want it to fire @ **2:15, 3:00, 3:45, 4:30** etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cron triggers are useful when you care about something running at specific times on the clock or calendar (a specific time each hour, minute, day, week, etc.).

When you care more about how much time passes between jobs (45 minutes), you should use a [SimpleTrigger](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/lesson_5.html). You can just tell it to repeat every 45 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following trigger:

```
ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
.WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
.WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInMinutes(45))
.Build();
```

Comment: This is Same as using a SimpleTrigger?

Comment: More or less... with this trigger you can set calendar based schedules as well (for example from Monday to Friday) which you cannot do with SimpleTrigger.

Answer (score 0):

The '/' syntax specifies the increment during the period and not a repeat interval. Admittedly a subtle and confusing difference.

In this case there is only one available increment (45 minutes) during the 60 minute period. The first number specifies the value to start with, in this case 0. So the job will only fire on the hour and at 45 minutes.

If the period can be divided by multiple increments, eg 0/10 then it will fire for each at each of those times, eg at 10, 20, 30 etc minutes.

If you want a job to trigger at a regular interval then you can use a Quartz `SimpleTrigger` with a `repeatInterval` specified.